# UK tax calculator

Tags: php, beginner, object-oriented, finance

I'm very much on the beginner end of the PHP scale but I have read plenty of the entry level books and completed the online training at teamtreehouse.com so I know the basics.

I'm at a point where I've built a tax calculator in PHP (UK income tax) and it works and is accurate but I have no clue if the code follows best practice. Most likely, it doesn't!

I need help to see how I go from a beginner programmer to an intermediate.  I want to make sure I'm on the right track before I start using a database for this project and converting it to an API.

My main class is below.  I learn by doing and then having people smarter than me tell me the areas I suck in so I can improve.  Hopefully you folks will be able to give me some pointers on areas to focus on.

I'm really trying to follow OOP practices and I know I have a lot to learn in that respect. Feel free to let me have it with both barrels.

```
<?php

require_once('tax_codes.php');
require_once('national_insurance.php');


class TaxCalculation {

    public $persona;
    public $taxRates;
    public $taxBand;
    public $taxFreeAllowance;
    public $personalAllowance;
    public $totalTaxableAmount;

/*
 * Sets the default values we need when the class is instantiated.
 * @param   array   $persona            User submitted inputs
 * @param   array   $income_tax_rates   Raw data for all tax years           
 */

    public function __construct($persona) {
        include('data/income_tax_rates.php');
        include('data/national_insurance_rates.php');
        include('data/student_loan_rates.php');
        include('data/childcare_voucher_rates.php');
        $this->persona = $persona;
        $this->taxRates = $income_tax_rates;
        $this->niRates = $national_insurance_rates;
        $this->taxYear = $this->persona["tax_year_is"];
        $this->taxBand = $this->taxRates[$this->taxYear]["rates"];
        $this->taxFreeAllowance = $this->taxRates[$this->taxYear]["allowances"];
        $this->studentRates = $student_loan_rates[$this->taxYear];
        $this->childCareVoucher = $annual_childcare_voucher_rates;
    }

/*
 * Takes two numbers and determines which is the lower figure.
 * @param   integer   $a,$b   Used to compare integers in other functions
 * @return  integer           The lowest value of the two checked                     
 */

    public function get_lower_figure($a, $b) {
        if ($a <= $b) {
            return $a;
        } else {
            return $b;
        }
    }

/*
 * Gets the personal allowance figure based on the users age.
 * @return  integer  The personal allowance for chosen tax year, by age               
 */

    public function get_personal_allowance() {
        if ($this->persona["age_is"] === "65_74") {
            $allowance = $this->taxFreeAllowance["personal_for_people_aged_65_74"];
            return $allowance;

        } elseif ($this->persona["age_is"] === "over_75") {
            $allowance = $this->taxFreeAllowance["personal_for_people_aged_75_and_over"];
            return $allowance;
        } else {
            $allowance = $this->taxFreeAllowance["personal"];
            return $allowance;
        }

    }

/*
 * Find and set the income allowance limit
 * @return  integer   The income limit for chosen tax year, by age           
 */

    public function get_income_allowance_limit() {

            if ($this->persona["age_is"] === "65_74" || $this->persona["age_is"] === "over_75") {
                $allowanceLimit = $this->taxFreeAllowance["income_limit_for_age_related"];
                return $allowanceLimit;
            } else {
                $allowanceLimit = $this->taxFreeAllowance["income_limit_for_personal"];
                return $allowanceLimit;
            }
    }

/*
 * Calculate the tax free amount that user is entitled to
 * @return  integer   The tax free allowance for chosen tax year           
 */

    public function get_tax_free_allowance() {
        $personalAllowance = $this->get_personal_allowance();
        $incomeAllowanceLimit = $this->get_income_allowance_limit();

        if ($this->persona["gross_annual_income"] > $incomeAllowanceLimit) {
            $deductFromAllowance = ($this->persona["gross_annual_income"] - $incomeAllowanceLimit) / 2;
            $personalAllowance = $personalAllowance - $deductFromAllowance;



            if ($this->persona["age_is"] === "65_74" || $this->persona["age_is"] === "over_75" ) {
                if ($personalAllowance <= $this->taxFreeAllowance["personal"]) {
                    $personalAllowance = $this->taxFreeAllowance["personal"];
                    $incomeAllowanceLimit = $this->taxFreeAllowance["income_limit_for_personal"];

                    if ($this->persona["gross_annual_income"] > $incomeAllowanceLimit) {

                    $deductFromAllowance = ($this->persona["gross_annual_income"] - $incomeAllowanceLimit) / 2;
                    $personalAllowance = $personalAllowance - $deductFromAllowance;
                }

                }
            }

        }

        if (is_numeric($this->persona["other_allowance_is"])) {
                $personalAllowance += $this->persona["other_allowance_is"];
            }

            if ($personalAllowance < 0) {
                $personalAllowance = 0;
            } 

        return $personalAllowance;

    }

/*
 * Set gross income to a float
 * @return  integer   Gross annual income         
 */

    public function set_gross_income() {
        $this->grossIncome = floatval($this->persona["gross_annual_income"]);
        return $this->grossIncome;
    }



/*
 * Finds the blind allowance for the chosen tax year
 * @return  integer   Blind persons allowance          
 */

    public function get_blind_persons_allowance() {
        $blind_persons_allowance = $this->taxFreeAllowance["blind_persons"];
        return $blind_persons_allowance;
    }

/*
 * Determines whether user is eligible for married couples allowance
 * @return  integer   Married couples allowance (10% of the allowance)          
 */

    public function get_married_couples_allowance() {
            $marriedAllowance = ($this->taxFreeAllowance["married_couples_over_75"] / 100) * 10;
            return $marriedAllowance;
        }

/*
 * Determines the personal allowance based on entered tax code
 * Replaces tax free allowance with calculated amount if the code isn't K
 * Adds the calculated amount to the total taxable amount if it is K
 * @return  integer   Personal allowance by tax code          
 */

    public function get_tax_code_personal_allowance() {
            $taxCodeCalculator = new TaxCodeCalculator($this->persona["tax_code_is"]);

            $this->taxCodePersonalAllowance = $taxCodeCalculator->get_personal_allowance_from_code();
            $this->taxCodeLetter = $taxCodeCalculator->taxCodeLetter;

            if (is_numeric($this->taxCodePersonalAllowance) && $this->taxCodeLetter === "K") {
                $this->totalTaxableAmount = $this->showGrossIncome + $this->taxCodePersonalAllowance;
                $this->showTaxFreeAllowance = 0;
            } elseif (is_numeric($this->taxCodePersonalAllowance) && $this->taxCodeLetter !== "K") {
                $this->showTaxFreeAllowance = $this->taxCodePersonalAllowance;
                $this->totalTaxableAmount = $this->showGrossIncome - $this->showTaxFreeAllowance;
            } 
    }

/*
 * Checks if the tax code is one of the special codes to work out
 * Compares the total taxable amount against the tax bands for chosen year
 * and works out the value of tax for each banding
 * @return     integer   Personal allowance by tax code          
 */

    public function calculate_tax_bands() {

        unset($this->taxBand["savings"]);

        if (isset($this->persona["tax_code_is"])) {
            $output = array();
            switch($this->persona["tax_code_is"]) {
                case 'BR':
                    // Basic Rate percentage
                    $this->showTaxFreeAllowance = 0;
                    $this->totalTaxableAmount = $this->showGrossIncome;
                    $bandPercentage = $this->taxBand["basic"]["rate"];
                    $percentageAmount = ($this->totalTaxableAmount / 100) * $bandPercentage;
                    $output["basic"] = round($percentageAmount);
                    $output["higher"] = 0;
                    $output["additional"] = 0;
                    return $output;

                case 'D0':
                    // Higher Band percentage
                    $this->showTaxFreeAllowance = 0;
                    $this->totalTaxableAmount = $this->showGrossIncome;
                    $bandPercentage = $this->taxBand["higher"]["rate"];
                    $percentageAmount = ($this->totalTaxableAmount / 100) * $bandPercentage;
                    $output["basic"] = 0;
                    $output["higher"] = round($percentageAmount);
                    $output["additional"] = 0;
                    return $output;
                case 'D1':
                    // Additional Band percentage
                    $this->showTaxFreeAllowance = 0;
                    $this->totalTaxableAmount = $this->showGrossIncome;
                    $bandPercentage = $this->taxBand["additional"]["rate"];
                    $percentageAmount = ($this->totalTaxableAmount / 100) * $bandPercentage;
                    $output["basic"] = 0;
                    $output["higher"] = 0;
                    $output["additional"] = round($percentageAmount);
                    $this->showTaxFreeAllowance = 0;
                    return $output;
                case 'NT':
                    // No Tax
                    return 0;

            }
        }


        $values = array();
        foreach ($this->taxBand as $key => $band) {

                    if ($band["end"] !== null || $band["end"] > 0) {
                        $band["amount"] = $this->get_lower_figure($this->totalTaxableAmount, $band["end"]) - $band["start"];
                    } else {
                        $band["amount"] = $this->totalTaxableAmount - $band["start"];
                    }

                $band["percentage_amount"] = ($band["amount"] / 100) * $band["rate"];
                $totalDeduction = $band["percentage_amount"];

                if ($totalDeduction < 0) {
                    $totalDeduction = 0;
                }

                $values[$key] = $totalDeduction;

        }
        return $values;

    }

/*
 * Takes total weekly income less deductions and works out the national
 * insurance contributions for the primary and upper bandings.
 * @return     integer   Annual national insurance contributions 
 */

    public function get_national_insurance_contribution() {
        $nationalInsuranceCalculator = new nationalInsuranceCalculator(
                                        ($this->persona["gross_annual_income"] - $this->showChildCareVouchers) / 52, $this->taxYear, $this->niRates);

        $totalNIContribution = $nationalInsuranceCalculator->get_ni_contributions();

        return $totalNIContribution;
    }

/*
 * Takes gross income less deductions and works out whether the income
 * is over the start amount before calculating the repayment amount
 * Student loans are also rounded down to the nearest pound.
 * @return     integer   Annual student loan repayment amount    
 */

    public function get_student_loan_repayment() {
        if ($this->persona["gross_annual_income"] >= $this->studentRates["start"]) {
            $deductableAmount = $this->persona["gross_annual_income"] - $this->studentRates["start"];

            if (isset($this->showChildCareVouchers)) {
                $deductableAmount -= $this->showChildCareVouchers;
            }

            $deduction = ($deductableAmount / 100) * $this->studentRates["rate"];
        }

        return floor($deduction);
    }

/*
 * Checks the pension amount for a % symbol and if found calculates the
 * percentage based on the annual income.  If there is no %, the entered
 * amount will be used instead.
 * @return     integer   Annual pension amount    
 */

    public function get_employers_pension_amount() {
        preg_match('/[%]/', $this->persona["pension_contribution_is"], $pensionPercentage);

        if (!empty($pensionPercentage) && $pensionPercentage[0] === "%") {
            $pensionPercentageAmount = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $this->persona["pension_contribution_is"]);

            if ($this->persona["pension_every_x"] === "month") {
                $monthlyIncome = $this->persona["gross_annual_income"] / 52;

                $pensionAmount = ($monthlyIncome / 100) * $pensionPercentageAmount;
                $annualAmount = $pensionAmount * 52;

                return $annualAmount;
            } else {
                $annualAmount = ($this->persona["gross_annual_income"] / 100) * $pensionPercentageAmount;

                return $annualAmount;
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->persona["pension_every_x"] === "month") {
                $monthlyIncome = $this->persona["gross_annual_income"] / 52;

                $pensionAmount = $this->persona["pension_contribution_is"];
                $annualAmount = $pensionAmount * 52;

                return $annualAmount;
            } else {
                $annualAmount = $this->persona["pension_contribution_is"];

                return $annualAmount;
            }
        }

    }

/*
 * Checks tax banding to see whether income is in a higher or additional band
 * If so, calculates the pension relief amount by multiplying the pension
 * amount by the tax band rate.
 * @return     integer   Annual HMRC pension relief    
 */

    public function get_hmrc_employers_pension_amount($pensionAmount) {
        $taxBands = $this->calculate_tax_bands();

        if ($taxBands["higher"] > 0 && $taxBands["additional"] === 0) {
            $pensionHMRC = ($pensionAmount / 100) * $this->taxBand["higher"]["rate"];

            return $pensionHMRC;

        } elseif ($taxBands["additional"] > 0) {
            $pensionHMRC = ($pensionAmount / 100) * $this->taxBand["additional"]["rate"];

            return $pensionHMRC;
        } else {
            $pensionHMRC = ($pensionAmount / 100) * $this->taxBand["basic"]["rate"];

            return $pensionHMRC;
        }

    }

/*
 * Checks whether the childcare voucher amount is within the limits allowed and 
 * if too high, returns the maximum allowed amount.  If the amount is in a higher
 * or additional tax band, a lower amount will be used.
 * @return     integer   Annual childcare voucher amount   
 */

    public function get_childcare_voucher_amount() {
        $income = $this->persona["gross_annual_income"];
        $taxBands = $this->taxBand;
        $annualAmount = $this->persona["annual_childcare_vouchers"];
        $rates = $this->childCareVoucher;
        $pre2011 = $this->persona["is_childcare_pre2011"];

        if ($annualAmount > $rates["basic"]) {
            $annualAmount = $rates["basic"];
        }

        if ($income >= $taxBands["higher"]["start"] && $annualAmount > $rates["higher"] && $pre2011 === "") {
            $annualAmount = $rates["higher"];

        } 

        if ($income >= $taxBands["additional"]["start"] && $annualAmount > $rates["additional"] && $pre2011 === "") {
            if ($this->persona["tax_year_is"] === "year2013_14" || $this->persona["tax_year_is"] === "year2014_15") {
                $rates["additional"] = 1320;

                $annualAmount = $rates["additional"];
            }

            $annualAmount = $rates["additional"];
        } 

        return $annualAmount;

    }

/*
 * Calculate the taxes for user and pull all figures together
 * @return  mixed   Return everything we need to populate the tax calculation table         
 */

    public function calculate_taxes() {

        $this->showGrossIncome = $this->persona["gross_annual_income"];
        $this->showTaxFreeAllowance = $this->get_tax_free_allowance();
        $this->totalTaxableAmount = $this->showGrossIncome - $this->showTaxFreeAllowance;
        $this->showTotalDeduction = 0;

        if ($this->persona["is_married"] === "on" && $this->persona["age_is"] === "over_75") {
            $this->showMarriedAllowance = $this->get_married_couples_allowance();
        }

        if ($this->persona["is_blind"] === "on") {
            $this->showBlindAllowance = $this->get_blind_persons_allowance();
            $this->showTaxFreeAllowance += $this->showBlindAllowance;
            $this->totalTaxableAmount -= $this->showBlindAllowance;
        }

        if (isset($this->persona["tax_code_is"])) {
            $this->get_tax_code_personal_allowance();
        }

        if (isset($this->persona["pension_contribution_is"])) {
            $this->showEmployerPension = $this->get_employers_pension_amount();
            $this->showPensionHMRC = $this->get_hmrc_employers_pension_amount($this->showEmployerPension);
            $this->totalTaxableAmount -= $this->showEmployerPension;
            $this->showTotalDeduction += $this->showEmployerPension;
        }

        if (isset($this->persona["annual_childcare_vouchers"])) {
            $this->showChildCareVouchers = $this->get_childcare_voucher_amount();
            $this->totalTaxableAmount -= $this->showChildCareVouchers;
            $this->showTotalDeduction += $this->showChildCareVouchers;
        }

        if ($this->persona["has_student_loan"] === "on") {
            $this->showStudentLoanAmount = $this->get_student_loan_repayment();
            $this->showTotalDeduction += $this->showStudentLoanAmount;
        }

        if ($this->persona["exclude_ni"] === "on" || $this->persona["age_is"] === "over_75" || $this->persona["age_is"] === "65_74") {
            $this->showNIContribution = 0;
        } else {
            $this->showNIContribution = $this->get_national_insurance_contribution();
            $this->showTotalDeduction += $this->showNIContribution;
        }

        if ($this->showGrossIncome <= $this->showTaxFreeAllowance) {
            $this->totalTaxableAmount = 0;
            $this->totalTaxDue = 0;
        } else {
            $this->deduction = $this->calculate_tax_bands();
            $this->totalTaxDue = $this->deduction["basic"] + $this->deduction["higher"] + $this->deduction["additional"];
            $this->showTotalDeduction += $this->totalTaxDue;
        } 

        $this->showNetIncome = $this->showGrossIncome - $this->showTotalDeduction;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a quick comment, before I take the time for a more thorough review [Coding standards are very important](http://www.php-fig.org). Try to adhere to them as much as you can. In this particular instance, you'll soon find that that will make all those `require_once` and `include` statements utterly redundant

Comment: I looked through the site you linked to but wasn't really sure what I was looking at.  Care to elaborate for a newb? Nevermind, I figured it out.  Looking at autoload now :)

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Hi lan is it possible for you to share the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot that could be improved so at least a couple of points. In case that you need further explanation I will gladly explain it in comments.

1. Having public class attributes is usually sign of bad design:

   ```
   public $persona;
   public $taxRates;
   public $taxBand;
   public $taxFreeAllowance;
   public $personalAllowance;
   public $totalTaxableAmount;
   ```

   You should initialize attributes in constructor or with `setAttributeName($attributeName)` methods:

   ```
   private $persona;

   public function setPersona($persona) { $this->persona = $persona; }
   ```

   If you need to access attribute outside of the class then you should have `getAttributeName()` methods:

   ```
   public function getPersona() { return $this->persona; }
   ```

   Inside class it is ok to access attribute directly using `$this->persona`.
2. Do not include files inside class method:

   ```
   public function __construct($persona) {
       include('data/income_tax_rates.php');
       include('data/national_insurance_rates.php');
       include('data/student_loan_rates.php');
       include('data/childcare_voucher_rates.php');
       $this->persona = $persona;
       $this->taxRates = $income_tax_rates;
       $this->niRates = $national_insurance_rates;
       $this->taxYear = $this->persona["tax_year_is"];
       $this->taxBand = $this->taxRates[$this->taxYear]["rates"];
       $this->taxFreeAllowance = $this->taxRates[$this->taxYear]["allowances"];
       $this->studentRates = $student_loan_rates[$this->taxYear];
       $this->childCareVoucher = $annual_childcare_voucher_rates;
   }
   ```

   It should be like this:

   ```
   public function __construct($persona, $taxRates, $niRates, $taxYear, $taxBand, $taxFreeAllowance, $studentRates, $childCareVoucher) {
       $this->persona = $persona;
       $this->taxRates = $taxRates;
       $this->niRates = $niRates;
       $this->taxYear = $taxYear;
       $this->taxBand = $taxBand;
       $this->taxFreeAllowance = $taxFreeAllowance;
       $this->studentRates = $studentRates;
       $this->childCareVoucher = $childCareVoucher;
   }
   ```

   - Constructor or `setAttributeName($attributeName)` methods should be used for passing variables from outside of the class to class.
   - What if you decide to use the class in some other project? It would always mean to move it together with other files.
   - Design like this is not easy to be tested by test frameworks.
   - You can find a lot of good articles about OOP, for example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/567768/Object-Oriented-Design-Principles).
3. Do not write method documentation like this:

   ```
   /*
    * Sets the default values we need when the class is instantiated.
    * @param   array   $persona            User submitted inputs
    * @param   array   $income_tax_rates   Raw data for all tax years
    */
   ```

   Better to write it like this:

   ```
   /*
    * Sets the default values we need when the class is instantiated.
    *
    * @param array $persona User submitted inputs
    * @param array $income_tax_rates Raw data for all tax years
    */
   ```

   - Imagine that you would have 10 params and then you would need to add
     11th with way longer name than other parameters, that would require
     indenting all other parameters.
   - Readability is the same without indenting.
   - Indenting might cause problems displaying documentation hints in some
     IDEs.
4. Do not use empty line between method documentation and method definition:

   ```
   /*
    * Takes two numbers and determines which is the lower figure.
    * @param   integer   $a,$b   Used to compare integers in other functions
    * @return  integer           The lowest value of the two checked
    */

   public function get_lower_figure($a, $b) {
       if ($a <= $b) {
           return $a;
       } else {
           return $b;
       }
   }
   ```

   It should be like this:

   ```
   /*
    * Sets the default values we need when the class is instantiated.
    *
    * @param array $persona User submitted inputs
    * @param array $income_tax_rates Raw data for all tax years
    */
   public function get_lower_figure($a, $b) {
       if ($a <= $b) {
           return $a;
       } else {
           return $b;
       }
   }
   ```
5. There is built in method for this in PHP, the method is called "min":

   ```
   public function get_lower_figure($a, $b) {
       if ($a <= $b) {
           return $a;
       } else {
           return $b;
       }
   }
   ```

   - [Documentation for min method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)
6. This can be simplified (applies to other issues like this as well):

   ```
   if ($personalAllowance < 0) {
       $personalAllowance = 0;
   }

   return $personalAllowance;
   ```

   It should be like this:

   ```
   return ($personalAllowance < 0) ? 0 : $personalAllowance;
   ```
7. This can be simplified (applies to other issues like this as well):

   ```
   public function get_blind_persons_allowance() {
       $blind_persons_allowance = $this->taxFreeAllowance["blind_persons"];
       return $blind_persons_allowance;
   }
   ```

   It should be like this:

   ```
   public function get_blind_persons_allowance() {
       return $this->taxFreeAllowance["blind_persons"];
   }
   ```
8. It is better to have single exit point in a method, that means not multiple return statements in a method.
9. Variable `$monthlyIncome` not used in method `get_employers_pension_amount()`, comment in code:

   ```
   if ($this->persona["pension_every_x"] === "month") {
       // This variable is not used anywhere before return statement
       $monthlyIncome = $this->persona["gross_annual_income"] / 52;

       $pensionAmount = $this->persona["pension_contribution_is"];
       $annualAmount = $pensionAmount * 52;

       return $annualAmount;
   } else {
       $annualAmount = $this->persona["pension_contribution_is"];

       return $annualAmount;
   }
   ```
10. Value in variable `$annualAmount` is reassigned right after it is assigned, method `get_children_voucher_amount()`, comment in code:

    ```
    if ($income >= $taxBands["additional"]["start"] && $annualAmount > $rates["additional"] && $pre2011 === "") {
        if ($this->persona["tax_year_is"] === "year2013_14" || $this->persona["tax_year_is"] === "year2014_15") {
            $rates["additional"] = 1320;
            // You assign value here, you do not use it for any operation
            $annualAmount = $rates["additional"];
        }
        // You reassign the value here, assignment above is not needed
        $annualAmount = $rates["additional"];
    }
    ```
11. `isset` vs `array_key_exists`:

    ```
    if (isset($this->persona["annual_childcare_vouchers"])) {
        $this->showChildCareVouchers = $this->get_childcare_voucher_amount();
        $this->totalTaxableAmount -= $this->showChildCareVouchers;
        $this->showTotalDeduction += $this->showChildCareVouchers;
    }
    ```

    You are using the `isset` method for checking if array key exists. It works, but there is special method for that called `array_key_exists`.
12. `""` vs `''`:

    If string does not contain any variables it is generally better to use `''`, because PHP does not need to check if there is variable inside the string and the interpretation of script is a bit faster.
13. Naming your class `TaxCalculator` would be more suitable, `taxCalculation` (or better `calculateTax`) would be more appropriate for a method.
14. Use consistent naming of your variables and methods.  Use `myMethodName` / `myVariableName` or `my_method_name` / `my_variable_name`, not both.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not too familiar with PHP, so just a few generic notes:

1. For this:

   > ```
   > /*
   >  * Sets the default values we need when the class is instantiated.
   >  * @param   array   $persona            User submitted inputs
   >  * @param   array   $income_tax_rates   Raw data for all tax years           
   >  */
   >
   >     public function __construct($persona) {
   > ```

   I'd use the same indentation level for both comments and functions since they're connected to each other:

   ```
   /*
   * Sets the default values we need when the class is instantiated.
   * @param   array   $persona            User submitted inputs
   * @param   array   $income_tax_rates   Raw data for all tax years           
   */
   public function __construct($persona) {
   ```

   You should also use consistent indentation in other places too.
2. Instead of the following function you could use PHP's built-in [`min`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) function:

   ```
   public function get_lower_figure($a, $b) {
       if ($a <= $b) {
           return $a;
       } else {
           return $b;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Don't use floating point varibles for currency, they are not precise.

   - [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/843804)
   - [How to deal with strange rounding of floats in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2248835/843804)
4. `persona` seems to be an array. I would consider creating an object for it as well as for its keys. With an `Age` object you could change this:

   > ```
   > if ($this->persona["age_is"] === "65_74" || $this->persona["age_is"] === "over_75") {
   > ```

   to a more type-safe version:

   ```
   if ($this->persona->age->isOver65()) {
   ```

   It would also reduce duplication of array keys though the code and would be easier to read.
5. `52` is used multiple times. You should create a named constant for it with a descriptive name.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I've taken your advice and started check my indentation, replaced that function with min() and I'm looking into creating a persona object.  I've not done that before so I'm doing some reading first.

Comment: @ian: I'm glad that you find it helpful. The `Persona` object should be similar to you `TaxCalculation` object, probably with setter/getter methods.